# how to make a function which return bmi?

Tags: javascript

I want a function which return the BMI. If my weight is 65 and my height is 1.8 so what will be my round BMI.

```
function bmiCalculator(weight, height) {
  var bmi = 65/(1.8*1.8);
  bmi = Math.round(bmi);
}

bmiCalculator();
```

I have tried so many time but I get 15 BMI and the expected is 20.
Can some body explain what is going behind the scene?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show your attempt.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: function bmiCalculator(weight, height){
    var bmi = 65/(1.8*1.8);
        bmi = Math.round(bmi);
        
}
bmiCalculator();

Comment: I've added that code to your question @SohailAfridi. Note the function doesn't return anything, nor are you logging anything so it's not clear where/how you're expecting to see a result.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, just make sure to use the function parameters and call it.

Also, name your params appropriately.

```js
/**
 * Compute BMI and round the result to an integer.
 *
 * @param {number} weightInKg - Weight in kg
 * @param {number} heightInMeters - Height in meters
 * @returns {int} rounded BMI result
 */
function bmiCalculator(weightInKg, heightInMeters) {
  return Math.round(weightInKg / (heightInMeters ** 2));
}

console.log(`BMI: ${bmiCalculator(65, 1.8)}`); // 20
```

Answer (score 0):

BMI is calculated by weight in kg dividing by height in meters multiplied by height in meters

```
const weight = 65;
const height = 1.8
const bmi = weight / Math.pow(height, 2);
console.log(bmi); // 20.061728395061728
console.log(parseInt(bmi)); // 20
```

Comment: Previous answer which is a function using Math.round is a betheer solution